# Динамический layout квадратной формы

Tags: android, android-layout

Как создать layout, адаптируемый под любой экран ("зажатый" между уже имеющимся textView сверху и низом экрана) квадратной формы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textview1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Похоже на то что вы хотели получить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!!!!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно помимо этого еще наложить TableLayout поверх уже созданного (таким образом) ImageView?

Comment: Добавить в конец TableLayout с теми же параметрами, что и у ImageView.